# Is there an examples of a JHipster Oracle 11g implementation around?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, jhipster

Is there an examples of a JHipster Oracle 11g implementation around?
I thought I had everything set up correctly, but still not able to run ./mvnw without the application throwing errors. Unfortunately not a lot is available on the specific error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project cdp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] error reading /Users/millera/.m2/repository/io/github/jhipster/jhipster-framework/3.0.3/jhipster-framework-3.0.3.jar; zip END header not found

I initially thought this was an issue with Maven on my system, but it seems to be working for other things, and if I run mvn --version I get back:
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.2/libexec
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with your maven local repository which for some unknown reason has a corrupted jar of jhipster-framework.

Try cleaning it up with `rm -rf /Users/millera/.m2/repository/io/github/jhipster` and restart your app with `./mvnw`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, it looks like that got me past that error and to the next which complaining about ojdbc again. I have it added in the POM but I seems to be having issues trying to install it via: 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=⁨ojdbc7.jar⁩ -DgroupId=com.oraclee -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: I'm getting a ton of errors surrounding the maven repo now:

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading /Users/millera/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-hibernate5-2.9.9.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR]